# Express.js Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest

I am setting up a login API using Express.js and MongoDB, connecting to it with a separate Vue app. The Vue app sends a POST request payload of an object containing two strings, an email and password. Upon sending the request, the Express app crashes with the following error:

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot remove headers after they are sent to the client`

From my understanding of other Stack Overflow questions, this error appears to be due to attempting to send multiple responses for a single request, though looking through my code, I can't find any instances where more than one response would be sent. Below is the API code in the Express app:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const users = await User.find({});
    let user = null;
    if (users) {
        user = users.find((user) => user.email == req.body.email);
    }
    if (!user) {
        res.status(400).send('Cannot find user');
        return;
    } else {
        try {
            if(await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                res.send('Logging in...');
                return;
            } else {
                res.send('Incorrect email or password');
                return;
            }
        } catch {
            res.status(500).send();
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Testing the API within the Express app using the VSCode Rest Client extension, the API appears to function correctly, without running into any errors or crashing. It's only when the API is called from the Vue app that the Express app crashes. The only other API I've setup within the Express app returns all users, which functions properly when called from the Vue app. Below is the POST request from the Vue app:

```
async login(credentials: any): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(apiLogin, {
            method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
        });
        const result = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Currently, I have tried commenting-out all but one response in the Express app, as well as removing the headers object from the Vue app's POST request as I didn't initially understand the error, but I still receive the same error when the request is sent. Every similar question I've found points towards multiple responses sent for a single request, but in my code, that doesn't seem to be the issue here, so I'm unsure as to what is causing this error.

Thank you for your time!